# Close question by linking to documentation instead of duplicate question

Tags: discussion, documentation, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387813/convert-wide-to-long-in-r-varying-date) which is closed for being a duplicate question. However, there is also a documentation link about the exact same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/2904/reshaping-data-between-long-and-wide-forms#t=201702221415580749699) that would give a precise answer to that question. Therefore, I was wondering if it is also possible to flag questions as duplicate by referring to documentation. Furthermore, if you have the choice, what would be the best? To link to the duplicate question, or link to the documentation item (since documentation is still in beta).

I am not a moderator myself, so I don't how obvious this question is to moderators.

Comment: It currently isn't possible, and I would probably avoid it. At least for now I'd probably let Documentation mature a bit more before starting to link the two, and I'd want to avoid RTFM-style closures.

Comment: I agree that documentation could age. However, in this case I don't see how this is RTFM-style. First of all, the goal of documentation is to provide examples and therefore it is not exactly a manual. Secondly, in this specific case, one of the examples answers the exact question of the OP. Therefore I think that providing a link to documentation could add value.

Comment: In this specific case I'd also want to hold off on it. I think that Doc page is not ready to be held up as a dupe target for a number of reasons. I might file some IRs against it shortly.

Comment: Actually, I guess I'll just go ahead and start with that.